# How to migrate IBM Domino web application content to WebSphere Portal?

Tags: lotus-domino

Scenario: I have an IBM Domino web application (.NSF) and contains divisions (refer to the image). I want to migrate the content (such as blogs, main content and the article) to my WebSphere Portal. What is the first thing to do?

My understanding in migration is database to database migration and seems I don't know where to find the database for my contents knowing that database in creating domino application is built in. Advance thanks!

Refer to this image: http://postimg.org/image/irxsjdk8p/

Answer (score 1):

The database *is* the NSF file - although it's possible that the information might be aggregated from several NSF files so you'll have to do some analysis. The first thing to do is to use the Notes client to identify the documents that contain the content that you want to migrate, check their properties to determine what NSF file they are stored in and what form they are based on, and then use Domino Designer to open the NSF file (or files, possibly) and analyze the form and determine which items contain the values that need to be migrated.

Comment: Suppose I have my MyWebApp.nsf containing XPages, Forms, etc. I created a form "ArticleForm" that saved the form content and display it the other division on the same page. I want to get the article content and I need to display it somewhere in my content manager or blog portlet in WebSphere Portal. Thanks Richard!

Comment: I presume there must be a view in MyWebApp.nsf that contains the documents you want to migrate. Other than telling you that, I really don't know what to say. Are you looking for a tool to do the migration? Are you looking to write code but you don't know how to read documents? This appears to be a very broad, and general question -- perhaps too broad for StackOverflow. Either that, or I'm just not understanding what you expect for answers.

Comment: Yes, ofcourse it has a view that handle my documents. That was I suppose to ask, If there's a migration tool that can migrate content of my domino web app to WSP? I know this is broad and very hard to understand what I am asking but thank you for the courage to answer. Very helpful.